# Missing pixels when rotating an object

Tags: c++, image-processing, algebra, rotational-matrices

So I created an ellipsoid but when I try to rotate it almost half of the voxels goes missing. Whether I do it using the rotation matrix or using the transfer matrix from one base to another, I immediately start losing pixels. If the ellipsoid is at 0 degrees, 90, 180, or 270, it looks fine. But as it travels in-between those angles, the background color starts peeking through in little holes everywhere on my object. I assume this is some kind of float to int conversion issue, but I don't know how to go about fixing it. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Look at your question.  Can you determine what is happening by the amount of information you provided?  Code or algorithm would be nice, after all, you did tag it as C++ but there is no C++ code.

Comment: All matrices transfer from one basis to another. It's what they do. Rotation matrices are the ones that transfer from orthonormal bases.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because when you draw your rotated shape, due to the rounding/truncation of coordinates, multiple source pixels map to the same target pixel, which means that there are target pixels that do not get any value.

The correct way to do this is to take all target pixels and perform the inverse transform, and collect the value that should be in the target pixel.  Potentially doing some interpolation.

Comment: Um. What's a *target pixel* in your explanation?

Comment: It's a pixel in the target image.   The "result" image.

Comment: *Target image* is equally vexing. If it is the image after the transformation, then the statement that a target pixel does not get any value does not make sense.

Comment: it does if you implement it like:  `for(srcCoords in srcImage)  dstCoords=transform(srcCoords); dstImage[dstCoords]=srcImage[srcCoords];`

Comment: There is no `dstCoords` in this code that does not get any value.

Comment: it depends on the transform.   if it does 2D rotation (not multiple of 90 degrees) followed by truncation to integer coords, then there usually is.